# basic jquery function and lack of understanding

Tags: jquery, html, css, if-statement

I'm trying to make a slider and i'm new to programming in general. this was an idea i saw someone else use but i have messed with it so much that i cant find the original code and don't know whats wrong. I understand how trivial this is and i've tried researching and i just cant comprehend the problem i suppose. When this code runs it doesn't display the first div on the first round but then every time after it does. Also, it hesitates after the last div while returning to the first.. here is the relevant code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var i = 1; // Counter
  $slides = $('.slides > .slide');
  $num = $slides.length; 
  setInterval(function() {
    if (i++ == $num) {
      $('.slide').removeClass('active').hide();
      $($slides[0]).addClass('active').show();
      i = 1;
    } 
    else {                    
      $('.active').removeClass("active").hide().next().addClass('active').show();
    }
  }, 1000); 
});
```

HTML for slides is:

```
<div class="slides">
  <div class="slide active">
    <img src="http://www.engraversnetwork.com/files/placeholder.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you hiding everything initially? If so, before the setInterval, show the active first slide. for removing the hesitation, select the first slide before the setInterval.

Comment: In the CSS. .active is given opacity 1 while .slide is given opacity 0. So the HTML gives .active to the first slide and if the CSS is read in a list then .active is last on that list. I'll try adding the first slide outside the function. Thank you

Comment: so i added    $($slides[0]).addClass('active').show();    above the function which solved the first problem of not displaying anything on the page load but there is still the problem after it hits the last slide. After the last slide it takes the time to display: none; on slide three but then waits the 1 second until displaying the first slide again.